# How to create a route with slug or id

Tags: laravel, routes, difference

How can I call the user's profile with an ID or slug over the route?
If the user calls his own profile it should be able to open it via slug profile / {slug}
If the privacy of the visited profile is 3, it should only be accessible via the ID. profile / {id}
In a different privacy, it should be able to be called only via slug.

I tried the code, but unfortunately it does not work.

```
public function index($param)
{
    $user = User::firstOrFail();

    if(Auth::user() === $user){
        $user = User::where('slug', $param)->first();
    }elseif ($user->profile->privacy === 3){
        $user = User::where('id', $param)->first();
    }else{
        $user = User::where('slug', $param)->first();
        }
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/profile/{param}', 'Profile\ProfilesController@index')->name('profile');
```

Comment: `$user` will never `=== Auth::user()` (exact match), they are separate instances. They might represent the same entity to you, but they are different instances.  `$user` might `== Auth::user()` though. `== != ===`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$param` parameter will receive user id or slug, so try below code:

```
public function index($param)
{
    $user = User::where('slug', $param)->first();

    if($user)
    {
        if($user->profile->privacy === 3)
        {
            // This user profile cannot access via slug
        }
        // User Accessible via slug
    }
    else
    {
        $user = User::where('id', $param)->first();
    }
}
```

User own profile and privacy level not in 3 profiles are accessible via slug, so you don't want to check is auth user accessing his own profile.